# Ubuntu 18.04 on startup error, [-f: command not found

Tags: bash, 18.04, permissions, bashrc, .profile

I booted to installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my system and faced the error and pressing Ok button does not work
[image]

The only thing I did was following the react-native installation instruction:
created a `.bash_profile` at `$HOME/.bash_profile` and gave permission as `.bashrc` or `.profile` which was `Me` and group `amir`. just to prevent do `source .bash_profile` every time I did add it (I am not sure) in `.bashrc` or `.bashprofile` that if the `.bash_profile` exists add it. just copy pasted the other `if` on the upper line.

so it seems there is a white space or some problem at that command (if I did add it to `.profile`). how can  I boot to Ubuntu now to make it correct?

Comment: The fastest way is using ctrl-alt-f3 to go to tty3 and login in there.

Comment: If he can't boot then `Ctrl+alt+f3` won't work!

Comment: tty3 should work before login so won't be affected by `.profile`, but I don't know how bad the account status is.  May not be logged in into bash as well.

Answer (score 1):

To edit those files use these steps:

1. Boot with installation media and select `Try Ubuntu`
2. Mount `root` at the point `/mnt`

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
   ```

   - Make sure that you know your root, i.e. the partition that `/` was mounted on during installation.
3. Then `chroot` into that location so you can edit your files:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
4. Now use your editor and edit that file your previously edited.

**NOTE:** If your lost just do `ls /mnt` to see where your going!!